# Using loop to get output in log file

Tags: odoo

I'm very new in python, I'm trying to pool products id from sale order line in odoo, but I did not get any output in log file. I need help.

```
class SOL(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def _get_sale_o_line(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        so_pool = self.pool.get('sale.order.line')
        for so_obj in so_pool.search(cr, uid, ids,context=None):
            logging.debug('Order Name: %s' so_obj.order_id)
obj=SOL()
obj._get_sale_o_line()
```

Comment: how/where do you call the **_get_sale_o_line** method?

Comment: after obj=SOL i've call the method and then i got an erro:raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404: Not Found

Comment: **how** ? what parameter do you pass it? Please edit your question.

Comment: please now check the code and suggest me what should I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call methods like that in Odoo. That class is part of an ORM.

[Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion.